# How to add nested Data Driven nodes in ZAP

Tags: zap

I wish to map a site with owasp zaproxy. The site uses data driven nodes in the URL in such a format to download image data for maps:
`https://subdomain.domain.tld/maps/<<region>>/<<version>>/tiles/<<zoom>>/<<x-chunk-idx>>/<<y-chunk-idx>>.png`
This creates a massive tree that I wish not to display. However I would like to display the individual nodes. When I create a data driven node for region it works fine. However when I try to nest the nodes it generates a mess. Node names start to have url escaped characters in them in the tree view or I get multiple nodes on the parent node.

I tried adding the regexes

```
region: https://subdomain.domain.tld/(maps/)(.+?)(/.*)
version: https://subdomain.domain.tld/(maps/.+?/)(.+?)(/.*)
etc
```

I have also tried to only use two regex groups, mixed two and three, include or not include the slashes in different groups. Nothing seems to work.

What's more I can't find information on how the data driven node is implemented. The built in help text and the [website](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/ddc/) explaining it are the same text, neither says what the groups actually represent. I also tried just to use right click and flag as data driven node, but after the first one it adds the text (ex `<<region>>`) for the previous data driven node in as a regex match, which of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/6867 nested Data Driven Nodes are not currently supported but can be acheived via scripts: https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2021-03-29-zap-2-10-0-features/#site-tree-control